# VNC Viewer with AutoX option

Tags: windows, remote-access, ssh, remote-desktop

I'm using `bVNC: Secure VNC Viewer` for Android. It has feature called AutoX. It finds or starts `x11vnc` and can automatically discover existing or create new X session when connecting through SSH. Looking for client with that option for Windows.